# Creating a probability density function for a particular dataset

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, data-analysis

I want to create a probability density function for a particular dataset. First of all, I calculate the mean and the variance of my dataset. So, I use the mean and the variance to create a probability density function, for example, Gaussian distribution. Is my thinking correct?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com may be a better home for this question.

Comment: A gaussian assumption is  not always justified, even if your distribution is symmetric.  You should do a normality test (at the very least, say, a normal qq plot). Otherwise, I suggest a nonparametric approach such as kernel density estimation as mentioned in my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to visualize the dataset.

For example, you have to consider if your data is symmetrical.

If your data is symmetrical and you believe that Normal distribution would be a good fit, then using the mean and unbiased estimator is indeed a common practice.

This Wikipedia [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution_fitting) describes your approach as follows:

> For example, the parameter
> $\mu$  (the expectation) can be estimated by the mean of the data and the
> $\sigma^{2}$ (the variance) can be estimated from the standard deviation of the data. The mean is found as $ m=\sum \frac{X}n$, where $X$ is the data value and
> $n$ the number of data, while the standard deviation is calculated as
> $s=\sqrt {{\frac{1}{n-1}}\sum {(X-m)^{2}}}$. With these parameters many distributions, e.g. the normal distribution, are completely defined.

Comment: Thank you for your advice...I visualize my dataset and it is not symmetric. I upload my visualization to another post because I cannot upload the picture....

Answer (score 0):

A nonparametric way to estimate a density corresponding to your data is through [kernel density estimation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation).

Given an iid sample $(x_1,...,x_n),$ this method estimates your density function as

$$\widehat f=\frac{1}{nh}\sum_{i=1}^n K\left(\frac{x-x_i}{h}\right)$$

for a suitable choice of a bandwidth parameter $h$ and [kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_(statistics)#In_non-parametric_statistics) $K(\cdot)$.

I encourage you to read the wiki article for details. Further lecture notes are [here](http://faculty.washington.edu/yenchic/18W_425/Lec6_hist_KDE.pdf).